# Pytorch not using GPU . Worked on Fastai

Tags: pytorch

My GPU Nvidia gtx1050 Ti

I am trying to train it on GPU but I only see CPU utilization 60-90 percent and GPU around 5 percent during training may be due to the copying of tensors to GPU I don't know. But it just goes up 5 percent and comes down.

I tried increasing batch size to 64 or 128 based on some solutions online but it just gives me Cuda out of memory error. I have used like 2.3gb out of 4gb and says need 120 MB and has only 110 mb.---- I dont even understand  how it works at this point

Then tried decreasing batch size to 16 then also got Cuda out of memory error saying need like 40 MB and has 16mb same 2.3 GB used out of 4gb

In the end it worked for 8 batch size but it only uses CPU no GPU

I used fastai with batch size 128 it works fine and uses gpu . I dont know where I did wrong. Any help appreciated. Below is my code wrote based on pytorch image classifier tutorial

Model Resnet pretrained True
has 205 labels with 117000 images approx as data for training. 
Just using pretrained weights such that weights will modify accordingly without freezing weights and not training from scratch I assume is what the code does. Feel free to correct me if I did something wrong or better solution. In the end I am just noob in pytorch .... My first code in pytorch

trainset....... PIL Image format with rgb converted to prevent error of 4 channel and removed if not opened by PIL --invalid images: corrupted image

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0") #0 device is my nvidia gtx 1050 ti when printed

model.fc=nn.Linear(2048, 205) 

from torchvision import transforms
t = transforms.Compose([            
 transforms.Resize(256),                    #[2]
 transforms.CenterCrop(224),                #[3]
 transforms.ToTensor(),                     #[4]
 transforms.Normalize(                      #[5]
 mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],                #[6]
 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )                 #[7]
 ])
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=8,
                                          shuffle=True)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print('yes gpu')
    torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
    model = model.cuda()

import torch.optim as optim
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(6):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels,img_name = data
        inputs = inputs.to(device) 
        labels = labels.to(device)
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        total=0
        correct=0
        if i % 2000 == 1999: 
            # print every 2000 mini-batches

            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            outputs = model(inputs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            print('Accuracy of the network on the batch size  images: %d %%' % (
                100 * correct / total)) #training accuraccy

            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Answer (score 0):

To monitor your GPU usage continuously you can use
`nvidia-smi --loop=1` in a terminal.

There are two things to look for, the usage of the GPU and the usage of the ram of the GPU, choose the maximum batch size such that you don't get a out of memory error.

Regarding the usage of the GPU, as long as it is computing, it should be approaching 100 %, it is possible that your data-loading process on CPU is slow and so that most of the time the GPU is waiting for the CPU to give it tensor to perform computation on. For instance, in your case, all transformations are performed on CPU, which takes some time.

You might want to launch another training, and watch closely how the GPU usages changes over time to decide what needs to be changed and if something needs to be changed.